# div with Min-height and another div with 100%

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` inside another `div`

First `div` has a min-height of 800px

Second `div` has a height of 100%.

I want height of second `div`to be the same that first one.

However i get this:  http://jsfiddle.net/gW4Hh/

Is it possible of any way??

Thanks!

Comment: second div should have `min-width: inherit;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple just use inherit

```
#container{
width: 100%;    
min-height: inherit;
background-image: linear-gradient(#a8a8a8, #ebebeb);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change this properties for this:

```
#container{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: inherit;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#a8a8a8, #ebebeb);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

css

```
body, html{
    height:100%;
}

.screen{
    width: 480px;
    height:100%;
    min-height: 800px;
    background: #F3E2A9;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    margin: 0 auto; /* Centramos la pantalla */
}
#container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#a8a8a8, #ebebeb);
}
```

[jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/gW4Hh/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `position: relative` and `position:absolute` for your second div, like that :

```
.screen{
    position: relative;
    width: 480px;
    min-height: 800px;
    background: #F3E2A9;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    margin: 0 auto; /* Centramos la pantalla */

}

#container{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#a8a8a8, #ebebeb);
}
```

By doing this, you will position the second div absolutely to the parent positioned element, which will give you the possibility to use `height: 100%`